# VS1010 Database Projects and reference data scripts

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, deployment, database-deployment, dbproj

Just wondering the best way to handle the following....

I want to have a VS2010 database project to keep the schema of my database in the dev, integration test and production environments in sync.

As part of the test and production environments I have a lot of reference data that needs to be loaded into the database.

For dev and test I can just recreate the database and use Post Deployment scripts to load the data. However, I cant really do this for the production environment as obviously it will have live data on it.

So what is the best solution to do this? I dont think I can use Post Deployment scripts to load the datbase, because in the case of an insert statement I would need to wrap each one inside an IF NOT EXISTS... clause and there are 1000's of rows.

Maybe its best to use the VS2010 + MSBuild tools to keep the schema up to date and then have a seperate solution for managing the data?

Or is there a solution to this that uses purely the tools in VS2010 + MSBuild?

Comment: Why are you limiting yourself to "purely the tools in VS2010 + MSBuild" only?

Comment: Can you suggest any different tools that could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution for live production enviroment - **not to use automatic updates at all!**

Use very well tested hand made update scripts in touch with your backend and frontend applications update

And there is always a good idea to have a fresh backup

Comment: +1 - you want it to work well, do it yourself. Do not use automatic updates.

Comment: I think this is the way forward. The current VS2010 tools don't appear to be flexible enough to handle static/reference data.

Answer (score 0):

How about truncating and rebuilding the reference data table each time? If there are constraints you can remove them and add them back at the end of the post-deployment script. Would that work for you?

Or is there a reason why you can't remove production reference data?

Answer (score 0):

For reference data you can have a script that handles an insert, update or delete depending if the data is already in the table or not.

Check out this [link](http://leon.mvps.org/StaticData/) for more details (this also includes a generator to help you generate your scripts).

Answer (score 0):

Use a populated database to  [generate merge statements](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Generate/88892/) that can be applied in Post-Deployment.
It might be a good idea to take out the DELETE clause though.